# Fixed width on the column, when window is resized?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have 2 main columns, seperated by a gridsplitter:

```
<Window x:Class="EnvironmentNet.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:caliburn="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
        Width="800"
        Height="400"
        Background="Black"
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
        >

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" MinWidth="300" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" MinWidth="400" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Background="Red" x:Name="Nav" Grid.Column="0" />
        <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="5" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Grid Background="Green" x:Name="Content" Grid.Column="2"  />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

This works fine, but when i resize the window, the left column starts to resize as well. How do i keep the left column in fixed width and make the right column stretch out instead, when the window is resized? The user should still be able to resize the left and right columns manually using the gridsplitter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set **Width="Auto"** for first ColumnDefinition.I have tried this . But it causes one problem It makes GridSplitter to be dragged upto Right Corner If thats not acceptable according to your requirement then it wont help.